# Событие отрисовки страницы WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть приложение с одним окном и несколькими страницами. Мне нужно выполнить действие сразу после того, как одна из станиц Page будет отображена на экране. Существует ли аналог события **Loaded**, срабатывающий сразу **после** отображения страницы на экране, а не перед ним?

Comment: Да, [есть](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.contentrendered?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/desktop/wpf/windows/?view=netdesktop-6.0#window-lifetime-events

Comment: Это для окна. Подскажите как использовать его со страницей. Или он срабатывает при загрузке новой страинцы?

Comment: @NikMAX Возможно вот [это](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)?

Comment: Loaded уже пробовал. Он срабатывает сразу перед отрисовкой окна, а мне нужно сразу после.

Comment: @NikMAX тогда перегружайте метод OnRender